# Is it possible to create a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, stl, pointers, vector, pure-virtual

Just wondering, because of a problem I am running into, is it possible to create a vector of pointers?  And if so, how?  Specifically concerning using iterators and .begin() with it, ie:  How would I turn this vector into a vector of pointers:

```
class c
{
     void virtual func();
};

class sc:public c
{
     void func(){cout<<"using func";}
};

sc cobj;

vector<c>cvect
cvect.push_back(cobj);
vector<c>::iterator citer

for(citer=cvect.begin();citer<cvect.end();citer++)
{
     citer->func();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vector <c> cvect` is not a vector of pointers. It is a vector of objects of type c. You want `vector <c*> cvect`. and the you  probably want:

```
cvect.push_back( new c );
```

And then, given an iterator, you want something like:

```
(*it)->func();
```

Of course, it's quite probable you didn't want a vector of pointers in the first place...

Comment: func() is a virtual function, so I guess vector of pointers is required here.

Comment: And if push_back() throws, you probably want to avoid leaking the new c.

Answer (score 17):

Sure.

```
vector<c*> cvect;
cvect.push_back(new sc);
vector<c*>::iterator citer;
for(citer=cvect.begin(); citer != cvect.end(); citer++) {
  (*citer)->func();
}
```

Things to keep in mind:

You'll need to cleanup after your self if you use dynamically allocated memory as I did in my example

e.g.:

```
 for(...) { delete *i; }
```

This can be simplified by using a vector of `shared_ptr`s (like `boost::shared_ptr`). Do not attempt to use `std::auto_ptr` for this, it will not work (won't even compile).

Another thing to keep in mind, you should avoid using `<` to compare iterators in your loop when possible, it will only work for iterators that model a random access iterator, which means you can't change out your code to use e.g. a `std::list`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible, and in fact it is *necessary* to use pointers if you intend your vector to contain objects from an entire class hierarchy rather than of a single type.  (Failing to use pointers will result in the dreaded problem of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) -- all objects are silently converted to base class type.  This is not diagnosed by the compiler, and is almost certainly not what you want.)

```
class c
{
     void virtual func();
};

class sc:public c
{
     void func(){cout<<"using func";}
};

sc cobj;

vector<c*> cvect;             // Note the type is "c*"
cvect.push_back(&cobj);       // Note the "&"
vector<c*>::iterator citer;

for(citer=cvect.begin();citer != cvect.end();citer++)   // Use "!=" not "<"
{
     (*citer)->func();
}
```

Note that with a vector of pointers, **you need to do your own memory management**, so be very careful -- if you will be using local objects (as above), they must not fall out of scope before the container does.  If you use pointers to objects created with `new`, you'll need to `delete` them manually before the container is destroyed.  You should absolutely consider using smart pointers in this case, such as the `smart_ptr` provided by [`Boost`](http://www.boost.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You have create `vector<c*>` for a vector of pointers. Then use `new` to allocate the memory for c objects and push them into vector. Also, don't forget that you have to `delete` yourself and vector.clear() will not release the memory allocated for c objects. You have to store c as a vector of pointers here, otherwise the call to the virtual function will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure.

```
// TestCPP.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class c
{
public:
    void virtual func() = 0;
};

class sc:public c
{
public:
    void func(){cout<<"using func";}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sc cobj;

    vector<c*> cvect;
    cvect.push_back(&cobj);
    vector<c*>::iterator citer;

    for(citer=cvect.begin();citer<cvect.end();citer++)
    {
        (*citer)->func();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please note the declaration of `vector<c*> cvect` and the use of `cvect.push_back(&cobj)`.

From the code provided, you are using iterator in a wrong way. To access the member an iterator is pointing to you must use `*citer` instead of `citer` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Boost Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/examples.html). It has several advantages over regular vector of pointers, like:

```
my_container.push_back( 0 );            // throws bad_ptr 
ptr_vector<X> pvec; 
std::vector<X*> vec;
( *vec.begin() )->foo(); // call X::foo(), a bit clumsy
pvec.begin()->foo();     // no indirection needed
```