# C++ Dynamically Linked List of 2 Classes Connected (RPG System)

Tags: c++, oop, reference

I am currently developing an RPG system for UNI work and I'm having trouble with the most efficient form of linking two classes together in a way that a creator **Character** will be able to use a created **Item** - the code is currently in the form of a dynamic linked list.

---

I have two classes

```
Character
itemtype

class item
{
 string itemtype 
 string itemname

    void item_search(item* ihead, item* &ipast, item* &icurrent)
    {
        string search;
        if (ihead==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"no item"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Enter item to serach for :"<<endl;
            getline(cin,search);
            icurrent=ihead; //current pointer goes to -> header
            cout<<icurrent<<" "<<search<<" "<<icurrent->itemtype<<endl; 
            while(icurrent!=NULL && search>icurrent->itemname)
            {
                cout<<"Item Type:"<<icurrent->itemtype<<" "<<cout<<icurrent->itemname<<endl;
                ipast=icurrent;  //Past = new current pointer
                icurrent=icurrent->inext; //current pointer = next pointer

            }
        }
    }
public:
    item()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Item Type: "<<endl;
        getline(cin,itemtype);
        cout<<"Enter Item Name:  "<<endl;
        getline(cin,itemname);
        cout<<"Enter Item Description: "<<endl;
    }
};

class character
{
    string charactername
}
```

What im trying to do is when creating a new instance of the itemspell class I want to be able to denote or point to a player.  I know I should have a pointer in player but I am not quite sure what to do from here...  I'm looking for suggestions, not a complete solution.

Comment: So you want every item to have a corresponding Character associated with it?

Comment: Why not just have a member variable of the Item class have a pointer to a Character class?

Comment: @bearsmahoney I'm not quite sure what you mean ? I'm essentially trying to figure out a way I can get the character to point to the itemheader of the link list. 
 
When a new item is created and added to the player it will check to see if there are any other instances in the list, and then add an item with the header being = to the footer of the first item and the end of this current item to become NULL ? 

I am not making sense sorry I am so confused.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/438676e0ccf79fcdd55318a14451bc59.png Here is an example of sort of what im getting at.

Comment: I'm really unsure of what your overall goal is. Thinking about it architecturally, does the Item really need to know what Character it belongs to? I would think not. It seems the more important relationship is for the Character to know exactly what items it's holding. In that case I would suggest that each Character have an array or vector (some sort of collection) of pointers to Items.

Comment: That is true I could go that way, I would have to declare the character first in the architechtural structure right ? basically, when I add an item though, I want the ability to assign it to a character.  - sorry for being a pain @bearsmahoney

Comment: No you're not being a pain. You could have a public method for a Character, something like, give_item(Item*) that adds that item to the Characters item collection.

Comment: Sure thing, I hope I was able to help a little bit :)

Comment: Sounds stupid but @bearsmahoney how do you create an array of pointers correclty ? what is the correct syntax ? I'm pretty new to Dynamic link lists and pointers/ adress locations.

Comment: If you're new to this stuff, I would recommend using a std::vector. They are pretty easy to work with and handle a lot of memory allocation/deallocation for you. This question has some good info. Also reading the c++ docs is always good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817263/is-it-possible-to-create-a-vector-of-pointers

Comment: yeah I looked at vectors ,unfortunately our lecturer wants us to uses classes and methods :/ we gotta do it in this format @bearsmahoney I'll give it a look for another time anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Classes and methods work perfectly fine with vectors. If you mean you need to use linked lists then I guess you're stuck making a linked list :)

Comment: Yeah were stuck using linked lists @bearsmahoney :/

Comment: Well you could still set it up the way I said before. Just have each Character class contain a linked list of Item pointers. Then the add_item(Item*) method would have to add an Item to the linked list, and the delete_item(Item*) method would have to delete an Item from the linked list (and have some way to fail if the Item doesn't exist in the linked list).

Comment: I'm just not sure how to go about it @bearsmahoney , Do i just create a copy of the item link list integer values for the current header and end of the link list ?

Comment: Honestly I think a tutorial like this will help much more than I can at this point: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24684/How-to-create-Linked-list-using-C-C