# how to correctly use vector of pointers to objects of class

Tags: c++

I wonder why the second part of the following code I wrote doesn't work. I am practicing vector of pointers to class objects. I tried two ways, one is to define a class object; the other is to define a pointer to the object. The second way failed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        int id;
        A(int id):id(id){}
};

int main()
{
    vector<A*> A_vec, A_vec2;
    A a(5);
    A_vec.push_back(&a);
    cout << A_vec.size() << "; id " << A_vec[0]->id << endl;


    A *a1;
    a1->id = 5;
    A_vec2.push_back(a1);
    cout << A_vec2.size() << "; id " << A_vec2[0]->id << endl;
}
```

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817263/is-it-possible-to-create-a-vector-of-pointers you need to use `new`

Comment: The correct use of pointers in a vector is to have a vector of smart pointers, the kind that handle deallocation of the target's memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second snippet doesn't work because you've never allocated memory for the object, so `a1` points nowhere.

```
A *a1 =  new A(5);

...

// Once you're done with `a1', release the memory.
delete a1;
```

Comment: Can I ask one more question? delete a1 will release the memory of the object in the second way, but it looks like in the first way memory will not be released. So does this mean we should use the second way? @NPE